# Como poner un video en un objeto tipo blob con javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, net, amazon-s3

podrian ayudarme estoy intentando poner un video que esta alojado en un S3 de amazon, este video genero una url compartida y lo puedo colocar en una etiquta de  html, pero mi intencion es ponerlo en una objeto tipo blob de javascript, he intentado descargar los binarios desde el back-end en C# pero es muy lento pasarlos nuevamente al cliente, les muestro parte del codigo utilizo ajax para generar todo el html

```
var video = response.sharePath;
var blob = new Blob([video], { type: "text/json;charset=utf-8" })
var urlblob = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
<video> <source  src="' + url+ '" type="video/mp4">'</video>
```

como puedo poner el video sin descargarlo de lado de back-end y solo del cliente?

Comment: No entiendo que solucionaría `Blob`.

Comment: lo que pasa es que no quiero que se vea la url compartida en el sitio sino algo parecido a las url de los videos de youtube  como esto blob:https://www.youtube.com/6127cebc-e8b5-487c-84e7-7590be0c9399

Comment: Ahora entiendo, pero de cualquier manera usando blob expondrías la url "original" en el cliente. Te convendría hacer un mini proxy en el backend.  Es decir "url_del_backend" --- redirije a ---> "url_en_S3"

Comment: muchas gracias entiendo lo que me dices, voy a investigar como hacerlo